# How can I active several hover event in some separated sibling components simultaneously by hovering on each of them?

Tags: javascript, css, reactjs, sass, styles

I have three separated React component (a button, an image and a paragraph for example) which each of them has its hover event styled in its separated scss file. **All of the components are sibling**. I want **each of these hover** events works **by hover on any of other** elements. Is it possible by scss or I should do it by React JS?  How should I do that?

Comment: I think we need to see some code.

Comment: Add a `:hover` style rule for the parent of the three elements.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could achieve that with `:hover` css pseudo-class on the parent element, and specify the ruleset with appropriate child selector. For example:

```css
div:hover img {
  /* some styling */
}

div:hover p {
  /* some styling */
}

div:hover button {
  /* some styling */
}
```

```html
<div>
  <img />
  <p>some paragraph</p>
  <button>Press me!</button>
</div>
```

You can read more about `:hover` [here](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/:hover), and about **css selectors** [here](https://developer.mozilla.org/pl/docs/Web/CSS/CSS_Selectors)